# Load html, then load images using Ajax in Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance, lazy-loading

Basically what I'm looking for is performance here.

```
$.post(link,     
  function(data){
         //removes the image that was displayed while loading
         $("#loadingImg").remove();

         //append the new content, into the content div
         //and add a div around the new content in order to lazy load
         $("#content").append('<div id="new-page">' + data + '</div>');
         //lazy load the images inside the new div
         $("#new-page").find("img").lazyload({ 
                 placeholder : "/images/white.png", effect : "fadeIn" });
  });
```

I want to use the jquery plugin, [lazy load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload), to lazy load images that are appended to some content. Right now I can tell that the loading time with and without the lazyload line of that code is exactly the same (it's loading about 20 images). I'm now assuming that the $("#content").append() line waits for all the images to load before appending.

**Is there any way to put the html in the page, halt the browser from loading the images in that html, and then load them as the user scrolls?**

By the way, even when I do:

```
data = '<div id="new-page-' + pageCounter + '">' + data + '</div>';
var newData = $(data);
newData.find("img").lazyload({ placeholder : "/images/white.png", effect : "fadeIn" });
$("#content").append(newData);
```

It still takes the same amount of time to load...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there any way to put the html in
>   the page, halt the browser from
>   loading the images in that html, and
>   then load them as the user scrolls?

Yes there, is: jQuery waypoints:
http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/

### Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/BbA9M/

### HTML:

```
<img id="first" src="" width="364" height="126" deferred="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" />

<div style="height: 500px; ">Some vertical space. Scroll to the bottom</div>

<img id="second" src="" width="364" height="126" deferred="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" />
```

The only drawback that I find in this HTML code is that the `deferred` attribute is non standard.

### jQuery:

```
$('img').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    // set the image src attribute from the deferred one, which has the real URL
    this.src = this.getAttribute('deferred');
}, {
    triggerOnce: true, // load the image just once
    offset: function() {
        // calculate where the event should be fired
        // in this case, when the whole image is visible
        return $.waypoints('viewportHeight') - $(this).height();
        // if you want to load the image when the top of it is visible change it for
        // return $.waypoints('viewportHeight');
    }
})
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you so much for the quick response. I think I will be able to get around being non-standard by using a hidden field directly below the image to store the value with a similar id to the image. I'll figure out a way. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

If you already know which images to load on the page, you can give empty src attribute to images when the page loads, then add the source on page load event.

```
<img id='image1' src='' />
```

empty src property

```
window.onload = function () {
  ... the image path list ...
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

// for loop then add the appropriate images in their correct place

... images[i].src = 'correct path';
}
```

Comment: *sigh* - Wouldn't mind seeing a more interesting / tackling answer to the question in mind rather than hard coding each direct image path in.

Comment: Use a hidden field to store the value of the src and then reference that hidden field. It's what I ended up doing and it's xhtml valid.

Comment: That is a very good alternative. the whole point is to be able to load the image when ever you want